# How to add new line in the xml which has custom tags?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on an offline story android app. but it' has a very big problem. whenever I add a paragraph in the story but all the text is mixing. I mean paragraph is not showing. see the image in the description to understand properly.

Example XML Code:

```
<root>
  <story_id>1</story_id>
    <story_title>Half of the Profit</story_title>
    <story_date>25/07/2017</story_date>
    <story_des>A rich man wanted to give a great feast to his friends. He got all kinds of dishes prepared but he could not get fish. He offered a reward to the man who would bring it. After some time a fisherman brought a big fish.

        But the gate keeper would not let him in till he had promised to give him half the reward.

    The fisherman agreed. The rich man was highly pleased and wanted to give him a lot of money, but the fisherman refused to take it. Instead, he demanded a hundred lashes on his back. All were surprised. At last the rich man ordered a servant to give him a hundred lashes.

        When the fisherman had received fifty, he asked them to stop as he had a partner in the business.

    It was the gatekeeper. The rich man understood the whole thing. He was given the remaining fifty lashes dismissed from the service. The rich man gave the fisherman a handsome reward.
   </story_des>
</story>                                                              
</root>
```

Output:

### [Screenshot of how it is looking in the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awT1u.png)

**StoryXMLHandler.java**

```
package com.example.util;

 import com.example.item.ItemStory;

  import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
   import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

   import java.util.ArrayList;

   public class StoryXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = "";
ItemStory item = null;
private ArrayList<ItemStory> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<ItemStory> getItemsList() {
    return itemsList;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    currentElement = true;
    currentValue = "";
    if (localName.equals("story")) {
        item = new ItemStory();
    } 
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {
    currentElement = false;
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("story_id"))
        item.setId(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("story_title"))
        item.setStoryTitle(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("story_date"))
        item.setStoryDate(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("story_des"))
        item.setStoryDescription(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("story"))
        itemsList.add(item);
}
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {
    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = currentValue +  new String(ch, start, length);
      }
    }                                                                          
 }
```

---

**StoryDetailsActivity.java**

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
    Id = i.getStringExtra("Id");
    Title = i.getStringExtra("Title");
    Description = i.getStringExtra("Desc");
    Date = i.getStringExtra("Date");


   private void setResult() {
    txtName.setText(Title);
    txtDate.setText(Date);

    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    String htmlText = Description;

    boolean isRTL = Boolean.parseBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.isRTL));
    String direction = isRTL ? "rtl" : "ltr";
    String text = "<html dir=" + direction + "><head>"
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/custom.ttf\")}body{font-family: MyFont;color: #999999;text-align:justify;font-size:14px;margin-left:0px}"
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + htmlText
            + "</body></html>";

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);

}
```

Comment: Most likely normalizedString is playing a role here. Do you have a schema for the XML?

Comment: No, I don't have a schema for XML. can you please tell me how to add schema for XML? I have tried <br> and /n but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<p>` tags to create a new paragraph, like this:

```
<root>
  <story_id>1</story_id>
    <story_title>Half of the Profit</story_title>
    <story_date>25/07/2017</story_date>
    <story_des>
        &lt;p&gt;A rich man wanted to give a great feast to his friends. He got all kinds of dishes prepared but he could not get fish. He offered a reward to the man who would bring it. After some time a fisherman brought a big fish.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;But the gatekeeper would not let him in till he had promised to give him half the reward.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;The fisherman agreed. The rich man was highly pleased and wanted to give him a lot of money, but the fisherman refused to take it. Instead, he demanded a hundred lashes on his back. All were surprised. At last the rich man ordered a servant to give him a hundred lashes.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;When the fisherman had received fifty, he asked them to stop as he had a partner in the business.&lt;/p&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;It was the gatekeeper. The rich man understood the whole thing. He was given the remaining fifty lashes dismissed from the service. The rich man gave the fisherman a handsome reward.&lt;/p&gt;
   </story_des>
</story>                                                              
</root>
```

Comment: you have told me to use \r and you have added \n in the paragraph! what should I use?

Comment: @RebirthDev. Sorry, its `\n`. See my edited answer.

Comment: See the result of your code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jmapfZ4X0UrCoECmJTDFUm3R6GjVvZ0X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RebirthDev With `\n`?

Comment: @RebirthDev I didn't realize that you are already using html tags. See my edited answer.

Comment: only last paragraph is showing. see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CO7vNaxIec1T1hBe8YOkMqjGUJG7-7sK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you sure all your paragraphs start with `<p>` and ends with `</p>`?

Comment: I see. It's because '<p>' and `</p>` are treated as start and end elements instead of text. Let me change my answer...

Comment: what can be the solution for that?

Comment: You are Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: Great. Glad to help!